# Запятая и местоимение ЧТО перед косвенной речью необходимы?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, косвенная

Если опустить местоимение **что** в этом предложении:

> *В комитете сказали, что можно, но только под вашей ответственностью.*

То запятая сохранится? Или так
не стоит делать?

> *В комитете сказали, можно, но только под вашей ответственностью.*

А можно поставить тире?

> *В комитете сказали — можно, но только под вашей ответственностью.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда передаётся косвенная речь с союзом ‟что”, то это обычное сложноподчинённое с изъяснительной связью главного и придаточного. Предложение: ‟В комитете сказали, что можно, но только под вашей ответственностью” — обычное изъяснительное сложноподчинённое. Если убрать союз ‟что”, то это будет уже бессоюзная связь с соответствующей предупредительной интонацией, которая возникла, когда убрали союз.Пунктуация будет такая же, как и при прямой речи, но только без кавычек и большой буквы. При прямой речи ставится двоеточие не просто так, а оно обозначает эту предупредительную интонацию при двоеточии — ‟В комитете сказали: ‟Можно, но только под ответственностью Виктора”. Точно такая же интонация, обозначаемая двоеточием, будет при косвенной речи при отсутствии союза и вообще в любом предложении с изъяснительной связью, если убрать союз.

Вот несколько примеров из Розенталя:

> Люди знали: где-то, очень далеко от них, идёт война (Аж).
> Я понимаю: вам трудно сейчас сказать о целях, которые преследует литература (М. Г.).
> Фёдор понял: речь шла о связи (Фурм.).
> Евреинов так хорошо доказывал мне: университеты нуждаются именно в таких парнях, каков я (М. Г.).
> Я тебе определённо скажу: у тебя есть талант (Ф.).

Не совсем понял вопрос сразу, потому что быстро писал ответы. Я сейчас вижу, что речь идёт о каком-то таком бытовом диалоге, где нет никакой предупредительной интонации. Я бы сказал, что в такой ситуации нужна запятая, просто чтобы обозначить границу предложения, потому что каких-то пауз здесь вообще нет.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: *В комитете сказали — **можно, но только под вашей ответственностью**.*

**Комментарий**

1. **Опускать союз** — это не совсем корректное выражение, хотя условно им пользуются.
2. Если нет союза, то мы имеем **другую синтаксическую конструкцию:** бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП) или вводное предложение.
3. В **неполном** предложении подходит только БСП, тогда нужно ставить **тире** как более сильный знак (для обозначения паузы).
4. В **полном** предложение **запятая** возможна, например: *В комитете сказали, такой документ использовать можно, но только под вашей ответственностью.*

В этом случае предложение "в комитете сказали" приравнивается к вводному предложению.

Примечание. Возможный вариант (по контексту): ***под вашу ответственность***